# How to copy all the contents of a database from one domain to another new database in another domain?

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, web-hosting

I have a database in phpMyAdmin hosted in a domain. Now, I want to copy all the tables & contents of this database to another new empty database in some other domain How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup old Database:

Click on a database or table name in the navigation panel, 
Then on the menu, click “Export”,
This will generate standard SQL statements that can be used to recreate your database/table.
You will need to choose “Save as file”, so that phpMyAdmin can transmit the resulting dump to your station.

Restore into new Database:

Click on a database name in the navigation panel, 
the properties will be displayed. Select “Import” from the list of tabs in the right–hand frame. In the “Location of the text file” section, type in the path to your dump filename, or use the Browse button. Then click Go.

Taken from https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/nl/latest/faq.html?highlight=backup#how-can-i-backup-my-database-or-table